# Make a single ssh connection instead of multiple connetions

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

Currently, this is how my code looks. Instead of re-connecting each time to the remote host to check for files, I would prefer to only make the connection once, search for all files and then exit. Any help in this matter would be useful!

```
    for file in $FILE_LIST

    do

    FILE=`echo $file | cut -f1 -d"~"`

    FILENAME=$FILE$YYYYMM

    if ssh username@servername test -e some/directory/location/"$FILE$YYYYMM"*; then

    echo "SUCCESS"

    else

    echo "FAILURE"

    fi

    done
```

Comment: cant you write a script for verifying all your filetypes and return some status?

Comment: @Nachiket sorry im not understanding the question.

Comment: Instead of firing a ssh connection query everytime, create a shell script doing your job on remote machine and get some status as output in a file or on stdout and run it in single ssh query.

Answer (score 0):

Example code.

This generates your list of filenames in the first loop, and pipes all the names into a single SSH call.

SSH remotely executes a loop which reads each filename and returns SUCCESS or FAILURE.

I have included the filename in the success/failure message, but you probably don't need that if you are just looking the existence of a failure condition.

```
for file in $FILE_LIST

do

    FILE=`echo $file | cut -f1 -d"~"`

    echo $FILE$YYYYMM
done | ssh username@servername "
           while read file
           do
              if test -e some/directory/location/\"\$file\"
              then
                 echo \$file:SUCCESS
              else
                 echo \$file:FAILURE
              fi
          done"
```

Remember to be careful with the quotes and dollar signs.  Escape them all because they must be evaluated on the remote host.